# HTTP Secure POST in C# to a Server

Tags: c#, post, https

Yesterday, I registered with Rackspace to have HTTPS, mainly to our authentication servers. The auth is accessed through calling: `https://oursite.com/auth/auth.php`

Through this article by [MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For our client (which now communicates with our servers to authenticate/register users through a secure HTTPS channel), we have this method:

```
public static string getResponse(string url, string postdata)
{
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(postdata);
    HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    myReq.Timeout = 20000;
    myReq.Method = "POST";
    myReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    myReq.ContentLength = byte1.Length;

    myReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    myReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    Stream newstream = myReq.GetRequestStream();
    newstream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);

    WebResponse response = myReq.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

We have setup a method to authenticate, `myReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;`, and also a `Cookie Container` to store the cookies.

When I navigate to `oursite.com/auth/auth.php?credentials`, no matter what I do, I get returned a `0`, which stands for not connected or no access granted.

When I try to request response headers from that URL, I get this error:

`The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.`

I'm not really sure what to do to initiate a secure connection to the HTTPS server in C#. Could someone give me some pointers on what to do, or perhaps what I am missing in my method?

Comment: I'm not really sure what else you're looking for. In HTTPS the security is handled at the transport layer, which is managed at a lower level. What do you mean by "When I navigate to..." Are you just going to the URL in your browser, or are you setting up an actual HTTP POST request via Fiddler or some other HTTP client?

Comment: Can you explain to me what you mean by `managed at a lower level`?

Comment: What I mean is that there is nothing you really need to do in your code in order to establish the connection. Message encryption (which is all that HTTPS provides) is usually handled by your operating system's Network drivers.

Comment: When I am POSTing that data in my C# client, wouldn't I need to enforce HTTPS over HTTP? I suppose I just need to establish a trusted connection to our servers via HTTPS, but how do I do that?

Comment: If you wanted to enforce `https` you would have to examine the value of the `url` parameter... and yes, you would do that in your code.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` does not allow access to the local certificate store, which might lead to some problems establishing a connection over HTTPS.

Comment: What changes should I make to remedy this issue? An update: it seems if I try to request headers through the `https://` URL of my site, I get an error `the underlying connection was closed: could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.` Does this indicate it a server-side issue?

Comment: It looks like it is probably an issue with the certificate.

Comment: Yeah, we are still waiting for the SSL certs to propagate. My question really is - how do I, in my C# code, utilize the HTTPS protocol to establish trust?

Comment: It appears that simply having `https://` in the URL I am POSTing to is enough, according to some articles I've read.